# Stop back from the intersection to allow the operator the space to complete the turn

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hello ~ Does "[stop back](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/stop-back)" in the following paragraph mean to return to the intersection later? Thank you!

"[If you are on a road that a large vehicle is turning onto, be aware that the operator of the vehicle may need to drive across the centre line, cut a corner, or use part of your lane to complete the turn. Stop back from the intersection to allow the operator the space to complete the turn.](https://www.alberta.ca/commercial-vehicles.aspx)"

Comment: It seems to mean 'stop a short distance before the intersection' (to allow a long vehicle to cut the corner if necessary).

Comment: @KateBunting - I'd prefer 'Stop sufficiently in advance of (or far enough before) the intersection to allow the operator the space to complete the turn.'